# How to push part of directories into GitHub and remain others locally?

Tags: git, git-push

There are many files in my local directory test.

```
ls  test
test1   test2   test3  test4 test5 tes6 test7
```

To push all the files in test

```
cd test
sudo git init
git add *
git commit -am  "push"
git push -f  origin master
```

All files from `file1` until `file7` pushed into my github repository.
Now how to push only `test1` `test4` `test5` `test7` into my github repository?

Here is my wordpress directory.

```
ls /var/www/html/wp
index.php        wp-blog-header.php    wp-includes        wp-signup.php
license.txt      wp-comments-post.php  wp-links-opml.php  wp-trackback.php
readme.html      wp-config.php         wp-load.php        xmlrpc.php
wc               wp-config-sample.php  wp-login.php
wp-activate.php  wp-content            wp-mail.php
wp-admin         wp-cron.php           wp-settings.php
```

All directories pushed instead of wp-content.

Comment: You push commits/changesets, you're not pushing files. If you commit those files to your local repository and push, they will be pushed alongside. The only way to avoid this is to not commit them to your repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those folders are empty, you need to add a file (any file) in it.

For instance, a `.gitkeep` empty file.

If they are not empty, the a `git add test1 test4 test5 test7` is enough.
Or:

- Add the other folders (you don't want to add) in a `.gitginore`.

  ```
  test10/
  ```
- Then you can `git add .` (no need for `*`), commit and push.

That will add everything except the folder you don't want.

Avoid `git add *`, as the '*' is interpreted by the shell.

Comment: git add test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6 test7 test8 test9

Comment: only test10 left

Comment: how about 100 directories to push ,only one left??

Comment: @it_is_a_literature I have edited the answer to propose an alternative way to add everything except a folder.